# wpf bind to element and to property

Tags: wpf, data-binding, bind

i have the following form:

[image]

i implemented it in MVVM the XAML looks like this:

```
<!-- Username -->
<Label Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource TypicalLabelStyle}">Username:</Label>
<TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource TypicalTextBoxStyle}" Name="UsernameTextBox"
            Text="{Binding SourceConnection.Username, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
            />

<CheckBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="CopyPasswordCheckBox">Copy Password</CheckBox>

<!-- Password -->
<Label Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource TypicalLabelStyle}">Password:</Label>
<TextBox Grid.Row="3"  Grid.Column="1" >
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style>          
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=CopyPasswordCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="TextBox.Text" Value="{Binding ElementName=UsernameTextBox, Path=Text}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=CopyPasswordCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="TextBox.Text" Value="{Binding SourceConnection.Password}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

the problem is in the Password textbox:
if the "Copy password" checkbox is checked, then the binding SourceConnection.Password is empty.
in the case it's not checked then i get the proper value bind.

(the copy password means that the text in the Username textbox will be copied to the Password textbox).
i dont want to hold a property for "Copy password" in the code and then ask if...".

Answer (score 0):

I would add a boolean to hold the checkbox state in your viewmodel.  Then in the viewmodel, you can capture username changes, check the checkbox state and update the password accordingly.